# Show that there exists $C>0$ such that $\|a+b\|\geq C\|b\|$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(E,\|.\|)$ be a Banach space and  $A,B$ two subspaces of $E$ such that $A\cap B=\{0\}$ where $A$ is closed and $B$ has finite dimension. Show that there exists $C>0$ such that $\|a+b\|\geq C\|b\|$ for all $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the restriction of the quotient map $E \to E/A$ to $B$.  This is an injective map of finite-dimensional spaces, so it has a bounded inverse.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a less elegant approach:

Let $\phi(b) = \inf_{a \in A} \|b+a\| = \inf_{a \in A} \|b-a\|$.  It is easy to check that $\phi$ is Lipschitz of rank 1
hence continuous. Furthermore, $\phi(b) = 0$ **iff** $b=0$.

The set $C=\{ b | b \in B, \|b\| =1 \}$ is compact since $B$ is finite dimensional, hence a minimiser of
$\phi$ on $C$ exists, and so there is some $\lambda>0$ such that
$\phi(b) \ge \lambda$ for all $b \in C$.

Then we have $\|a+b\| \ge \lambda \|b\|$. 
If $b=0$, this is immediate. Otherwise we have
$\|a'+{1 \over \|b\|} b \| \ge \lambda$ for all $a' \in A$, choosing $a' = {1 \over \|b\|} a$ yields the desired result.